# Riesz Fischer theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

I was wondering about the following: I read that Fischer-Riesz says that $L^2([0,1])$ is isomorphic to $l^2(\mathbb{N})$. Now it is obvious, that this should not depent on the fact which compact subset $K$ you choose in $L^2(K)$, but my question is: Is $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ also isomorphic to $l^2(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: Yes, it is. Every separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: I have something in mind, that the space needs to have a countable orthonormalbasis to be isomorphic to $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, is this true?

Comment: Yes, and those are precisely the separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces. That's not hard to prove. Do you want to have a go at it?

Comment: we get immediately a contradiction if we assume that X is separable and has an orthobasis that is not countable. now, give me 2 minutes to think about the converse.

Comment: okay, taking rational coefficients and so on, will do the converse, thank you Daniel Fischer.

Comment: Right. Now, can you show the separability of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Answer (score 0):

The spaces $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ are isomorphic. This result uses the facts that that the infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $L^2$ is separable, and that all infinite dimensional separable Hilbert spaces are isomorphic to $l^2$. (We prove this last statement by constructing an orthonormal basis and introduce an operator that maps $L^2\to l^2$. Then verify it is "onto" and "one-to-one").